# jdbc_river not fetching all rows

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am using jdbc river to fetch all sql data into elasticsearch. But although I can clearly see that my database has much more rows, jdbc_river is only fetching like 4-5 rows.

This is the curl statement that I have used:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "strategy": "simple",
    "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
    "user": "test",
    "password": "password",
    "sql": "select * from eventcomplete",
    "poll": "24h",
    "max_retries": 3,
    "max_retries_wait": "10s"
  },
  "index": {
    "index": "paymentcomplete",
    "autocommit": "true",
    "type": "mysql",
    "bulk_size": 100
  }
}'
```

Can someone help me out with this, I am probably missing some parameter in the curl statement.

Comment: I think it should work. Please check the log if any issue are there.

Comment: reduce bulk size and adjust configurable settings. As @Roopendra said, check your logs.